# r - check is all elements of a list match a vector exactly

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, grepl

I have a list element `list_1` and then a vector `vec_1`. I would like to be able to identify if all the elements of a list element are found in the vector. They need to match exactly and if a list element is not found, that element should be printed. For example, if I loop through `list_1[1]` it would come back `TRUE` but if I loop through `list_1[2]` it returns `foo` and `bars`.

```
list_1 <- list(x = c("apple", "toast"), y = c("foo", "bar", "bars"))
vec_1 <- c("pear", "apple", "toast", "x", "foos", "bar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(list_1, function(x) if(all(x %in% vec_1)) TRUE else setdiff(x, vec_1))

#$x
#[1] TRUE

#$y
#[1] "foo"  "bars"
```